# Accessing Container from Windows 10

Tags: docker

I'm using Windows 10 and having a container instance listening at 0.0.0.0 10080 at this host. Ports are mapped as well. I know using docker inspect that the container IPV4 address is 172.17.0.2 but I'm getting **connection refused** when trying to connect and I don't see the container IP address using 'ipconfig /all'. Is that ok to not have container IP address in ipconfig utility?

Please someone help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The `docker inspect` IP address isn't useful, and can't be reached on many platforms.  Don't bother looking it up.

Comment: The mapped ports (`-p` option) are open on the host machine. You can use `localhost`.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that a docker container is an independent computer running on a different network, connected by what we called a docker bridge.

ipconfig will only list interface that are directly connected to you, so you can only see the bridge. You can’t see interface behind that bridge because it’s in a different network. There is no way for you to access the container from your Windows directly because they are not neighbors.

Now, when you do port mapping, let’s say your app inside the container is listening on 0.0.0.0:10080. Then you expose it to host port 8080. That means docker is creating some sort of tunnel between container port 10080 and your windows port 8080.

You can then access your container’s port from the host (Windows) from (pick one)

- localhost:8080
- :8080
- :8080

This is because all of those IP points to your host/computer and are directly connected interface inside your host.

You can’t access the container IP address without using service discovery because your computer needs a route information to reach that container, due to it not being directly connected with your host.

So, it’s normal that the IP that you saw from docker inspect does not exists from ipconfig command. It’s not your direct neighbor. However, note that from the container’s perspective, every container inside the same docker network can reach each other. So, if you have other container inside the same docker network, they need to use 172.17.0.2:10080 to reach your app. Or, you can use it’s service name because docker have internal service discovery inside it’s network.